# multi client error with java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, client, chat

Below is the code for a client and server which handles multi user chat.  But when one client writes "quit" my others current connected client also terminates and I can't then connect another client.  Can anybody help with this?

Here is my client code:

```
class TCPClientsc {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String modifiedSentence;
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(inetAddress);

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(inetAddress, 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        CThread write = new CThread(inFromServer, outToServer, 0, clientSocket);
        CThread read = new CThread(inFromServer, outToServer, 1, clientSocket);
    }
}

class CThread extends Thread {
    BufferedReader inFromServer;
    DataOutputStream outToServer;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    int RW_Flag;
    public CThread(BufferedReader in, DataOutputStream out, int rwFlag, Socket clSocket) {
        inFromServer = in;
        outToServer = out;
        RW_Flag = rwFlag;
        clientSocket = clSocket;
        start();
    }
    public void run() {
        String sentence;
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (RW_Flag == 0) {// write
                    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

                    // System.out.println("Writing ");
                    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
                    if (sentence.equals("quit"))
                        break;

                } else if (RW_Flag == 1) {
                    sentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                    if (sentence.endsWith("quit"))
                        break;
                    System.out.println("(received)" + sentence);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                inFromServer.close();
                outToServer.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
class TCPServersc {
    static int i = 0;
    static SThread tt[] = new SThread[100];
    static SThread anot[] = new SThread[100];
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String client;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            i++;
            System.out.println("connection :" + i);
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromMe = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            tt[i] = new SThread(inFromClient, outToClient, tt, 0, connectionSocket, i);
            anot[i] = new SThread(inFromMe, outToClient, tt, 1, connectionSocket, i);
        }
    }
}

// ===========================================================
class SThread extends Thread {
    BufferedReader inFromClient;
    DataOutputStream outToClient;
    String clientSentence;
    SThread t[];
    String client;
    int status;
    Socket connectionSocket;
    int number;

    public SThread(BufferedReader in, DataOutputStream out, SThread[] t, int status, Socket cn, int number) {
        inFromClient = in;
        outToClient = out;
        this.t = t;
        this.status = status;
        connectionSocket = cn;
        this.number = number;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (status == 0) {
                clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                StringTokenizer sentence = new StringTokenizer(clientSentence, " ");

                // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if (sentence.nextToken().equals("login")) {
                    String user = sentence.nextToken();
                    String pass = sentence.nextToken();
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    int flag = 0;
                    while ((client = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if ((user.equals(client.substring(0, 5))) && (pass.equals(client.substring(6, 10)))) {
                            flag = 1;
                            System.out.println(user + " has logged on");
                            for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                                if (t[j] != null)
                                    t[j].outToClient.writeBytes(user + " has logged on" + '\n');// '\n' is necessary
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        while (true) {
                            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                            System.out.println(user + " : " + clientSentence);
                            for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                                if (t[j] != null)
                                    // '\n' is necessary
                                    t[j].outToClient.writeBytes(user + " : " + clientSentence + '\n');
                            }
                            // if(clientSentence.equals("quit"))break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (status == 1) {
                while (true) {
                    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                    if (clientSentence.equals("quit"))
                        break;

                    System.out.println("Server: " + clientSentence);
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                        if (t[j] != null)
                            t[j].outToClient.writeBytes("Server :" + clientSentence + '\n');// '\n' is necessary
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                // System.out.println(this.t);
                inFromClient.close();
                outToClient.close();
                connectionSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably the problem is in the server, not the client, since one client can affect another. We'd have to see the server code.

Comment: Please format your code readably and remove commented-out statements.  If you ask somebody to invest time reading your code you should be willing to make it readable.

Comment: We're not inclined to wade through your copious and badly formatted code. Reduce it and format it, then you *might* have a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has a number of problems.

- First off, in the future, please post *smaller*, concise code fragments that are well formatted.  I just had to basically reformat everything in your post.
- I see a couple of places where you are catching but doing nothing with exceptions.  This is *tremendously* bad practice.  At the least you should be printing/logging the exceptions you catch.  I suspect this is contributing to your problems.
- I find the `RW_Flag` very confusing.  You should have two client threads then.  One to write from `System.in` to the server and one to read.  Don't have one client thread which does 2 things.  Same with `status` flag in the server.  That should be 2 different threads.
- Instead of `int flag = 0;` in the server, that should be `boolean loggedIn;`.  Make use of booleans in Java instead of C-style flags and use better variable names.  The code readability will pay for itself.  Same for `status`, `RW_flag`, etc..
- Instead of huge code blocks, you should move contiguous code out to methods: `handleSystemIn()`, `handleClient()`, `talkToServer()`.  Once you make more methods in the your code, and shrink down the individual code blocks, it makes it much more readable/debuggable/understandable.
- You need to have a `synchronized (tt)` block around each usage of that array.  Once you have multiple threads that are all using `tt` if the main `accept` thread adds to it, the updates need to be synchronized.

I don't immediately see the problem although the spagetti code is just too hard to parse.  I suspect you are throwing and exception somewhere which is the reason why clients can't connect after the first one quits.   Other than that, I would continue to use liberal use of `System.out.println` debugging to see what messages are being sent where.